# Exception from a Spring WebFlux Mono interrupts Mono.zip

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive, spring-webclient

Let's say that I have two calls using spring webclient. Both are defined as follow, with an exception thrown in .**onStatus** :

```
public Mono<Model> getCall(String path) {
    webClient.get()
            .uri(path)
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, errorHandler())}
```

And this is the Exception function **errorHandler()** :

```
private Function<ClientResponse, Mono<? extends Throwable>> errorHandler() {
    return clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(ErrorResponse.class).
            flatMap(errorBody -> Mono.error(new CustomException(clientResponse.statusCode().value(), "exception", errorBody)));
```

On my Mono.zip, I defined it as follow :

```
Mono.zip(getCall(call1),
         getCall(call2))
         .block;
```

The problem is, if one of the calls throws an exception, I can no longer get at least one of the result. Tried using :

```
.onErrorContinue(CustomException.class, (error, output) -> log.error("CustomException !" + error + output))
```

So how can I handle exceptions with Mono.zip, like we do with try catch, but without stopping the execution and getting the results of successful calls ?
And Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your output has an empty state you can do something like:

```java
.onErrorResume(CustomException.class, e -> Model.empty())
```

If you don't have empty state you should wrap the output into `Optional`:

```java
.map(Optional::of)
.onErrorResume(CustomException.class, e -> Optional.empty())
```

In any case these operators should be chained to the `getCall` method. For example:

```java
public Mono<Model> getCall(String path) {
    return webClient.get()
            .uri(path)
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, errorHandler())     
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Model.class)
            .onErrorResume(CustomException.class, e -> Model.empty());
}
```

Comment: This is actualy a valid solution, but I did not mention the constraint  (my bad), I cannot edit the code of the Monos, I only had access to the call and the mono.zip

Comment: that doesn't make too much difference, you can still do `Mono.zip(getCall(call1).onErrorResume..., getCall2()....)` or create a private method as a wrapper around `getCall` so you don't need to duplicate

Comment: Using onErrorResume in the call solved my problem , thanks !

Comment: Just one more thing, do you know how can we return an object different than Model instead of Mono.empty() , in another mono ofc

Comment: Not sure I get the question. If you want to return a different type of object in case of error, then you'll need to change the return type of the method so it is a supertype of Model and the type of the  different object.

Comment: I found a workaround, it is by extending a class from the original one, and adding attributes that I need. Not the best way to do it, but it did the trick